# Can't access data in .xlsx file using pandas.read_excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, vba

I am trying to access data in an .xlsx file that the user can provide using `pandas.read_excel` and `io.BytesIO`. If I try to parse the data like this:

```
def parse_contents(contents, filename):
content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')
decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
if 'csv' in filename:
    # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV file
    return pd.read_csv(
        io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))
elif 'xls' in filename:
    # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
    return pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(decoded))
```

the function `parse_contents` returns

```
   Unnamed: 0                                   Unnamed: 1
0         NaN                                          NaN
1         NaN  Bitte aktivieren Sie Macros um fortzufahren
2         NaN                                          NaN
3         NaN                                          NaN
4         NaN            Please activate Macros to proceed
```

although I thought an xlsx file does not hold any macros. Interestingly for a different file the parsing seems to work find and I get all the data inside the file.

What do I need to do to completely remove macro functions from an Excel file?

Edit:

The issue remains if I use `filename` directly in `pd.read_excel` like this:

```
def parse_contents(contents, filename):
    if 'csv' in filename:
        # Assume that the user uploaded a CSV file
        return pd.read_csv(filename)
    elif 'xls' in filename:
        # Assume that the user uploaded an excel file
        return pd.read_excel(filename)
```

Comment: Does passing the filename to read_excel and read_csv fail for some reason? Why is bytes IO necessary?

Comment: Good question! It looks like it does not make a difference and I can't remember why I implemented so strangely. However I still have the same issue when I use `read_excel` on filename directly.

Comment: @Axel is this for a school assignment?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. The message was actually very misleading. I just had to specify the Excel sheet that I want to read to get it to work.